# Fluxbox startup file not working

Tags: linux, fluxbox

I am placing apps into my fluxbox startup file as per the instructions, however nothing starts up except fluxbox.

It doesn't matter what app I try, so it isn't an app problem.

here is my startup file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# fluxbox startup-script:
#
# Lines starting with a '#' are ignored.

# Change your keymap:
xmodmap "/home/josh/.Xmodmap"

# Applications you want to run with fluxbox.
# MAKE SURE THAT APPS THAT KEEP RUNNING HAVE AN ''&'' AT THE END.
tint2 &
tilda &

# And last but not least we start fluxbox.
# Because it is the last app you have to run it with ''exec'' before it.

exec fluxbox
# or if you want to keep a log:
# exec fluxbox -log "/home/josh/.fluxbox/log"
```

I have also tried tests such as "touch ~/testwoked" and such, nothing works.

It makes no difference if the file is executable or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `startfluxbox` instead of `fluxbox` when you are going to launch fluxbox.

(you didn't specify how you launch fluxbox but i am guessing here with some kind of experience)